# How can i display list on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<nav>
<a href="login.html" class="dropdown-content" style="text-align: center"><span id="login">您好</span><i class="login"></i></a>
<a href="9.html"><i class="like"></i></a>
<a href="7.html"><i class="file"></i></a>
<a href="4.html" style="text-align: center"><span id="counter">0</span><i class="drink"></i></a>
</nav>
```

what can i make a list on login when mouseover(hover)?

```
#login{
    color: #cb3e31;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 31px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: like the photo,i want my mouse hover "login" it can display the list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First wrap your list using div element (easier to handling) or show one by one element

```
<nav>
    <a href="login.html" class="dropdown-content" style="text-align: center">
       <span id="login">您好</span><i class="login"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="list">
        <a href="9.html"><i class="like"></i></a>
        <a href="7.html"><i class="file"></i></a>
        <a href="4.html" style="text-align: center"><span id="counter">0</span><i class="drink"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    $("#login").hover(
      function() {
        // show element
        $('#list').show();
      }, function() {
        // hide element
        $('#list').hide();
      }
    );
</script>
```